# How to Compute Visibility

Tags: meteorology, precipitation, barometric-pressure

I have the following data about a region, and would like to compute the visibility for that region, i.e. the distance that a person could see ahead of them.

I have:

1. precipitation (mm/day)
2. dewpoint(degree C)
3. temperature (degree C)
4. relative humidity (%)
5. wind speed (km/h)
6. pressure (kPa)

Does anyone know how I can compute some meaningful visibility measure out of this? This is for a computer model I'm using to model something else entirely, which needs visibility. So I'm stuck having to reconstruct that information from what I have

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: You need atmos. particulate matter concentrations to calculate visibility. See e.g. [Malm et al. (1994)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/93JD02916) or [Pitchford et al. (2007)](http://dx.doi.org/10.3155/1047-3289.57.11.1326) for formulas. The formula of Malm  et al. (1994) is also provided by [Matthias (2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/acp-8-5077-2008). You might assume some standard aerosol particle profile. However, this is not optimal ... . Maybe have a look onto the [IMPROVE Homepage](http://vista.cira.colostate.edu/improve/) (Interagency Monitoring of Protected Visual Environments).